# Cannot fix "Add library 'Gradle: com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:1.10.0' to classpath" (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, jvm

so I need to import a specific class (TexturePacker):

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker;
```

however, I receive the error above.

Normally, I added this to my build.gradle under **dependencies**:

```
classpath 'com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:1.10.0'
```

The problem still remains.

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: You should check the output of your Gradle build for errors. Gradle can be really chatty. :-)

Comment: The only thing I get is "Cannot resolve symbol 'TexturePacker'", not sure what else to look for...

Comment: Have you rebuilt gradle after adding the dependency? just getting that out of the way since I've done that before too.

Comment: I bet (!) you get more output from Gradle! I know Gradle very well for a long time and there is no way it just tells you "Add library ... to classpath". Check your Gradle output. What does `./gradlew assemble` say?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `project(":core")` dependencies

`api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"`

This is assuming you define your gdxVersion, if not you can replace with a specific version. Maybe its easier to run this tool again
https://github.com/tommyettinger/gdx-liftoff
and copy over the generated files if you have other errors.